# Magento 2 - Ajax is not calling Controller

Tags: magento2, custom, controllers, ajax, jquery

I tried to make a simple ajax-call to my controller.

Somehow I don't get a valid response.

**MyCompany/MyModule/Index/GetAjax.php**

```
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Index;

class GetAjax extends \Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction {

        public function __construct(
               Context  $context,
               \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        ) {

            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }


        public function execute() {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $result */
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        return $result->setData(['success' => true]);
       } 
}
```

**MyCompany/MyModule/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="mymodule" frontName="mymodule">
            <module name="MyCompany_MyModule" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/test.js**

```
define(['jquery'],
    function ($) {
         $(document).ready(function() {

              $.ajax({

                url : 'mymodule/index/getAjax',
                type : 'GET',
                data: {
                    format: 'json'
                },
                dataType:'json',
                success : function(data) {              
                    alert('Data: '+data);
                },
                error : function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

         });
    });
```

I get my error message and in my console I get

> JQMIGRATE: jQuery.parseJSON requires a valid JSON string.

Besides if I try to enter `mymodule/index/getAjax` url in my browser there is a

> Error 500 (internal server error)

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I updated my answer: Your controller should extend from `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Error 500 (internal server error)` - something went wrong on the server side.

We need to add `use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context` at the first of class. Or, change `Context` to  `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context`. Remove the comma `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,`.

Your controller should extend from `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`

Add the json variable `$resultJsonFactory`.

```
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class GetAjax extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    ......

}
```

In your Ajax function, need to remove (or add json format data with `JSON.stringify`)

```
data: {
      format: 'json'
  },
```

Remove `var/generation` and try to make the Ajax again.

There is a note that it's not good: making the Ajax request when the document DOM ready.

Comment: Although it did not solve the error. Thank you, I completly forgot that. I only used  $(document).ready for testing.

Comment: Still not working? Try to remove `var/generation`?

Comment: Sadly no, i still get a Error 500.

Comment: Is there any error log? You check the network and see your Ajax request?

Comment: Ah! I saw that you forgot to add the json variable `protected $resultJsonFactory;`

Comment: I added the `protected $resultJsonFactory;` and also `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` I still get the same Error Message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50140/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-trytofly).

Comment: @TrytoFly Can you is in chat now? I'm in.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with

```
$result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
```

replace with

```
$result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
```

Complete code

```
 <?php

namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Index

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class GetAjax extends Action {

    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
           Context  $context

    ) {

        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute() {
    /* @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $result */

        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        return $resultJson->setData(['success' => true]);
   } 
}
```

for reference you can see **vandor/magento/module-search/Controller/Ajax/Suggest.php**

Comment: This sadly did not solve the problem.

Comment: @TrytoFly added the complete code that i am using also the example in magento too

Answer (score 2):

Error is due to url

```
define(['jquery'],
    function ($) {
         $(document).ready(function() {

              $.ajax({

                url : 'http://www.yourdomain.com/mymodule/index/getAjax',
                type : 'GET',
                data: {
                    format: 'json'
                },
                dataType:'json',
                success : function(data) {              
                    alert('Data: '+data);
                },
                error : function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

         });
    });
```

Use above code url should be `http://www.yourdomain.com/mymodule/index/getAjax` instead of `mymodule/index/getAjax`

Comment: I tried that, does not make a change. I still recieve the same error´s.